# How to select dynamic value drop down which loads during run time

Tags: drop-down-menu, protractor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92wPR.png)I am not able to select the dynamic value of the drop down which loads during run time. I tried using Sendkeys to select the values of the drop down however the index position changes when user selects the value.

The UL tags comes and goes off when user clicks on the menu to select value.

I have attached the DOM and drop down details as part the ticket.Ineed to select values in firefox and chrome browsers and able to perform search accordingly.

Also, please find the locator which i have identified for the same.

Comment: You should include your [mcve] as searchable, copyable text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
var ele= element(by.cssContainingText('your locator here', 'Text of the option you want to select'));
```

For mor info refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Comment: Hi, the data is loading dynamically and we cannot locate the element. The UL tags gets displayed during run time.

Comment: That should not be a problem. Do it manually and get the element. So while running the test you can wait until the element is present.